# Copying one datepicker value to another on select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have following jquery script code on one of my views:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    getTotal();
    setDates();
});

$("#form1").on("input", function () {
    getTotal();
    CalculateDays();
    setDates();
});


function getTotal(){
var totalcart = 0;
    $('#form1 > table').each(function() {
        $(this).find("tr").each(function(){
            if(( $( this ).has( ".inputdays" ).length > 0) && ($(this).has("#shoppingcart").length > 0)){
               var total = $(this).find(".inputquantity").find("input").val() * $(this).find(".hotelprice").html() * $(this).find(".inputdays").find("input").val();
               $(this).find("#hoteltotal").text(total);
               console.log(total);
               totalcart += parseInt(total);
        }
            else if(($(this).has("#shoppingcart").length > 0)){
               var total = $(this).find(".inputquantity").find("input").val() * $(this).find(".price").html();
               $(this).find("#carttotal").text(total);
               totalcart += parseInt(total);
               console.log(total);
            }
            console.log("total: " + totalcart);
        });
    });
    $("#total").html(totalcart);
}

function CalculateDays() {
    $('#form1 > table').each(function () {
        $(this).find("tr").each(function () {
            var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
            var firstDate = new Date($(this).find("#datetimepicker1").find("input").val());
            var secondDate = new Date($(this).find("#datetimepicker2").find("input").val());

            var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));

            if ((!isNaN(diffDays)) && (firstDate.getTime() < secondDate.getTime())) {

                $(this).find(".inputdays").find("input").val(diffDays)
                getTotal();
            }
            else {
                $(this).find(".inputdays").find("input").val("0");
            }
        });
    });
}
function setDates() {
    $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', beforeShowDay: NotBeforeToday,
        onSelect: function (dateStr) {
            $("#datetimepicker2").val(dateStr);
            $("#datetimepicker2").datepicker("option", { minDate: new Date(dateStr) })
        }
    });
    $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker({

    });
}
```

in my html these datepickers are declared like this:

```
 <td id="shoppingcart">
     <div id='datetimepicker1'>
     <input type='date' class="form-control" />
     </div>
 </td>
 <td id="shoppingcart">
    <div id='datetimepicker2'>
        <input type='date' class="form-control" />
    </div>
 </td>
```

I just want to copy the currently selected value in datetimepicker1 to datetimepicker 2, later I want to disable dates that come before the selected date. This code doesn't seem to work however. What is the problem here?

As seen on this picture, when selecting a date in datetimepicker1, the value in datetimepicker2 (checkout field) isn't set to the selected value:

[image: Datepicker]

I'm am trying to copy the value of datetimepicker1 to datetimepicker2 in the function setDates(). I have tried multiple methods who all did not work. Could this be because I need to declare it in my other functional functions?

Comment: strange you have the format for dates as dd-mm-yy in your screenshot, but code suggests your format is yy-mm-dd

Comment: What random datepicker are you using? jquery ui? a plugin?

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery UI. I have adapted my original post a bit, with all my script code included. Maybe those interfere with my setDays() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the value of the element with ID of `datetimepicker2`, but that is just a `div` element.  On further review it seems your `datetimepicker1` would also suffer from the same problem.  The IDs you use with the `datepicker` function from jQuery should be `input` elements, as far as I know.

There were a few possible places for errors in your code, that is why presenting an example with the code that you can't get to work is a good way to debug.  I have created a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ve0b6fkt/

Also notice to set the value of the jQuery `datepicker` you need to use the `setDate` method: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input id='datetimepicker1' class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input id='datetimepicker2' class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
      $("#datetimepicker2").datepicker('setDate', dateStr);
      $("#datetimepicker2").datepicker("option", {
        minDate: new Date(dateStr)
      })
    }
  });
  $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

jQuery's rock-solid documentation: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I have changed the html and left the JS unchanged, but it did not do anything. I adapted my original post with all my JS script functions, could it be because these interfere with my setDays() function?

Comment: The method without changing the HTML and only changing my function also has the same problem. The problem must be in my other functions that interfere with it? I know this code you suggested and other methods should work, since the demo's also work.

Comment: hmm, the best way to trouble-shoot your problem is to create an example of what you're trying to do on JS Fiddle or you can even set it up in Stack Overflow using this tool: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Also check your `NotBeforeToday` variable.

Comment: What's wrong with my `NotBeforeToday` variable? I have tried taking away this variable but that obviously did not fix anything. Haven't found the issue yet so far. When googling I come along your solutions or other alike solutions for the datepicker, I'm clueless on why it does not work in my project.

Comment: In your code you had not defined it.  So the code will throw an error the way it is posted in your question.

Comment: @L.T please see my updatd answer.  I added a working example in JSFiddle of what it seems you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I checked your updated answer, tried it in a new project and it works. I also tried your HTML, so a new table independantly from mine in the project it should work in. Again, it did not want to work. I assume something is just wrong in my project, which I don't find. I have datepicker correctly installed so I've got no clue. Nothing you can do about it though, I know this code works. I'll tick your answer as the correct one, you were a huge help nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: @L.T Also make sure you're using all the tools available.  I always check the console in the browser.  This is where you'll see error messages firing from the Javascript.  It will be slightly different depending on which browser you use.  LIke I use chrome -> https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
onSelect: function () {
        $('#datepicker2').val(this.value);
    }
```

as an onSelect function for your first datepicker.
Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xyp7khfe/

Having in mind my comment, here is the html code that you should use:

```
<td>
     <div>
     <input id='datetimepicker1' type='date' class="form-control" />
     </div>
 </td>
 <td>
    <div>
        <input id='datetimepicker2' type='date' class="form-control" />
    </div>
 </td>
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier, I also found that to be the easiest. But it doesn't work, I included more script code in my original post, which is also on the view. Could it be because these functions interfere with my setDays() function?

Comment: as it is stated in jeffery_the_wind's answer you should put input ids for datepickers and not divs

Comment: I have tried that, same  problem occurs. The problem must be in my other functions then?